# How can I perform an UPSERT on a CSV file using Apache Calcite?

Tags: csv, apache-calcite

I tried executing the query below

```
"INSERT INTO " + schema + "." + fileName+"  '(' id,name ')' VALUES (3,'abc')")
```

I am not sure whether Calcite supports UPSERT or not.

But I referred to [the reference](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html) which shows different queries.

If it's not possible using Apache Calcite, then please let me know what other libraries I can use to perform UPSERT into a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Calcite doesn't currently support executing UPSERT statements. There has been [recent discussion](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/calcite-dev/202003.mbox/%3CCACcefgdhXOp0nt62f-w3Z6cPnEim-ferC3RCr2mFbrm%2B3oi5fw%40mail.gmail.com%3E) of this on the project mailing list so it's possible this will be supported in the future.

Comment: But in this doc https://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html they have given all the queries.

Comment: @kavyansh That documentation is for the parser. The parser can parse `UPSERT` statements. But they can't be executed.